# string contains unexpected characters when copied from google translator

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, google-translate

I copied the following text from google translator

> End Date time should be greater than Start Date Time

when I console log it prints following

```
End\M-B\240Date\M-B\240time\M-B\240should\M-B\240be\M-B\240greater\M-B\240than\M-B\240Start\M-B\240Date\M-B\240Time
```

also when I try to split this string it returns a single element of the string

```js
const str = "End Date time should be greater than Start Date Time"; // this text is copied from google translator. Not typed using keyboard
console.log(str.split(" ").length);
// logs 1
```

Does anybody have any idea why the copied text contains **\M-B\240**?

Comment: I don't know what `\M-B` is, but `\240` is a "no-break space" (according to https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html and https://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Comment: Can you please explain what _exactly_ “copied from google translator” means?

Comment: @CBroe i need this , because the app support multi language . I use google translator to translate the text and paste the text into corresponding json file and show into the html based on selected language

Comment: i think M-B means multibyte characters

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, copying a result from the Google translator result field results a simple string, without the additional characters. How exactly are you copying and pasting the text?

Comment: … and that’s why I was asking; what are the _exact_ steps to reproduce what you are talking about? Are we talking about the translation on the web, one of the specific native mobile apps, …?